# How to play a sound that is another file

Tags: java, audio, startup, joptionpane

I am making a game and wanted to add sound for my character selection page. So I created a working java file that plays the song, but how do I get the song file to play on startup of my character selection screen?

***Note:*** *Both files are in the same package.*

```
package comp_sci;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class PlaySound
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws Exception
  {
    // open the sound file as a Java input stream
    String gongFile = "music.wav";
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);

    // create an audiostream from the inputstream
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

    // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
  }
}
```

This is my sound file. To get this to play in my other program I've tried the code below but it did not work.

```
PlaySound winn2 = new PlaySound();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your PlaySound class, create a method called `playSound` which contains the code to play the song

```
public void playSound(String filename) {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
}
```

To call this method on the start up, use the following code

```
PlaySound winn2 = new PlaySound();
winn2.playSound("music.wav");
```

The reason your code wasn't working is that the main() method is used if you are starting with that class. If you want to run the code, you either need to create an instance of the class, or use static methods.

Comment: I'm im not understanding

Comment: The main method only executes if you start with that file. If you do what you did in your question, the main() method will not execute. You must put your code in a public method and call it from your menu code like in my question

Comment: so do I delete my music code and just paste what you wrote? But what do I fill in in the spot filename?